# Django Models - insert foreign key values using Shell

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to save values for my Models through Django Shell . I am beginner in Django. I have crated three models. I inserted values in models one by one.i created Dept first and inserted all Dept Values.Created Student and inserted all student related values. Now i am trying to insert values in course which contains two foreign key studentId and dept id . How to insert values for Student model using Django Shell.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Student(models.Model):
    studentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    registe_dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.studentId, self.firstname,self.city)


class Dept(models.Model):
    deptId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    deptName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.deptId, self.deptName)

class Course(models.Model):
    courseId=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseId, self.courseName,self.student.primary_key,self.dept.primary_key)
```

Thank you for helping 
Jordan

Answer (score 5):

You can insert the student and dept instances directly when inserting foreign key values:

```
student = Student.objects.last()
dept = Dept.objects.last()

course = Course.objects.create(courseName="My course", student=student, dept=dept)
```

`.last()` is the last one created, but you can get the instances however you like.

---

Also, you don't need to manually create primary keys. Django does it automatically for you. Each instance of a model has a `pk` value automatically assigned. That is if you don't need a differently named primary key. So the `__str__` method in `Course` could be:

```
def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseId, self.courseName,self.student.pk,self.dept.pk)
```

Comment: Hi Vedran ,     thank you for quick Response. What if i have created 4-5 objects for student in row and i would like to insert 2 created record with course. I am not sure how to retrieve PK and use it in syntax. I will be thankful to you if you can show me to do it ...

Comment: You can query every Django model like `Model.objects.get(field=value...)`. So for your student model it would be something like `student = Student.objects.get(firstname=MyName, lastname=MyLastName)`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried following syntax but unable to insert data. 
if i try to create null object like c1 = Course() and try to use that object it still gives error.

`s1 = Student(firstname='test',middlename='M',lastname='test',city='test')
s1.save()
for dept:
d1 = Dept(deptName='Computer')
d1.save()
for course:
course = Course.objects.create(courseName='Java',student=s1,dept=d1)`

Resulted in ""ValueError: "" needs to have a value for field "courseId" before this many-to-many relationship can be used."

Comment: I figure it out.. need to save course with dept first and then need to add student.. I am not sure if i can combine both in one step.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found out how to do it . 
`

```
  c1 = Course(courseName='Java',dept=d1)
   c1.save()
   c1.student.add(s1)
   c1.save()
```

`
Need to do it in separate steps. I am not sure if i can save dept and student both at a same time in Course. 
Jordan

Comment: You can't. A model instance gains the private key (pk) value only when you save the model, prior to that it is `None`. And when adding a related model instance to another one as its foreign key it needs to have the pk value in order to set it as the foreign key.